# Dividing space with spheres

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, 3d

I heard that maximum number of spaces that can be divided with n spheres is $\frac{1}{3}(n^3-3n^2+8n)$, as cited by this site: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpaceDivisionbySpheres.html

I tried to solve this but was unsuccessful, and also failed in searching for the proof. Any help would be very apperciated. Thank you.

Comment: [THIS](https://www.quora.com/How-many-parts-can-the-n-spheres-divide-a-space-into) might be useful.

Comment: see page 105-106 on Yaglom, A. M. and Yaglom, I. M. [Challenging Mathematical Problems with Elementary Solutions](http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/0486655369/ref=nosim/ericstreasuretro), Vol. 1. New York: Dover, 1987. (the 2nd ref in your link).